# Windows Phone 8 Wifi Default Gateway

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, wifi

Does anyone know how to get the Network (Wifi) connect details in code.
IPAddress / Subnet Mask / Default gateway?

I can see these listed in the WiFi settings of the phone, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in C# code.

I can get the connection IP information using;  NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()  and querying the objects but I really need the Default Gateway address.